# How can I implement the JavaScript code below in my angular component using typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to implement this JavaScript functionality in my angular component. I am new to JavaScript and angular and this has taken too much time. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
$('.carousel.carousel-multi-item.v-2 .carousel-item').each(function () {
   var next = $(this).next();
   if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
   }
   next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
   for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    next = next.next();
    if (!next.length) {
      next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
   }
});
```

Comment: Don't. This is jQuery code and it's a terrible, terrible match with Angular. Do everything the Angular way, OR everything the jQuery way, but don't mix both. The reason is, they are totally different frameworks with radically different ways of working. They have no clue about each other's presence and actions, and this will necessarily lead to a clumsy application, full of hacks and workarounds.

Comment: Typically, if you want a carousel in Angular, use an Angular plugin, don't try to adapt and hack a jQuery carousel into an Angular app.

Comment: As @JeremyThille already mentioned, angular is responsible for rendering and manipulating the DOM and if you’re interfering with it using jQuery, you might get some unwanted results. See [ng-mat-carousel](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-materialize-carousel) on stackblitz for example.. (there's a ton of possible carousels out there, you have to see & test which one works best for your requirements)